# Why should anyone use the new google wysiwyg editor?

Tags: javascript, wysiwyg

Yesterday google [introduced](http://closuretools.blogspot.com/2010/07/introducing-closure-library-editor.html) their wysiwyg editor and I was really exited.

However it seems to be kind of heavy.

[Online demo](http://closure-library.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/closure/goog/demos/editor/editor.html)

[image: Demo Screenshot]

[Firebug Network Traffic http://img441.imageshack.us/img441/3279/firebug.jpg](http://img441.imageshack.us/img441/3279/firebug.jpg)

It took my Firefox 8 seconds to download all 180 requests.
The network traffic was 2MB.

What is the point of using it anyway?

Comment: Quick comment - if this is used across multiple sites then all js should be in cache as it delivered from Google, not the best argument for this but still a valid point.

Comment: @Rippo - That's not quite true. The `Expires` header on most of these files is only 5 minutes in the future, so even if they don't modify their files and your browser doesn't have to download the actual data, you still **do** have to request them again to see if they've changed. And since most browsers are configured to have only four active requests open at a time, it takes a long time to clear those 180 requests. I would expect that Google will eventually combine the files like Yahoo does. But what they have now takes me 8-10 seconds to load on a 100Mb connection. That's insane.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a richer and more versatile editor than the other ones floating around. There is more opportunity for customizing the actions bound to various key, for example. Other editors are more of the "take it or leave it" persuasion.

One would expect that your browser will cache the admittedly fat JavaScript download associated with this editor, so that the next time you visit this site, there will be no noticeable delay. Google Mail works that way for me. 2 MB every time would be an imposition; 2 MB once would not bother me.

I had someone asking me just a couple of days ago if there wasn't something like a collaborative editing site "for dummies", where the editing capabilities were limited to an easily understood subset. Google's editor would allow me to put together an editor exactly meeting this person's requirements.